# How to import emulator data while the emulator is running?

Tags: firebase, firebase-tools

I'm using the firebase emulator in my cypress tests, but some of my tests require that I make changes to user authentication, storage objects, and firestore data. I'd prefer to reset all emulator data before each test, but it would be too slow to restart the emulator each time.

**Is it possible to simply trigger an import of the emulator data dynamically while it is still running?**

Answer (score -1):

You can use Firebase CLI commands, Specifically the **'firebase emulators: export'** and 'firebase emulators: import' to import data into the Firebase emulator while it is still running state. Check out this for further details [Create Import emulator data while the emulator is running.](https://github.com/RobinaMirbahar/Google-Cloud-Solutions/blob/main/Import%20emulator%20data%20while%20the%20emulator%20is%20running.)

Comment: "Error: emulators:import is not a Firebase command". I confirmed this using "firebase emulators --help" and because it is absent from the docs https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure

Comment: @NateMay it is there in the document verify https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure

Comment: I'm sorry, but there is only an `--import` flag that can be added to the `emulators:start` command.  There is no `emulators:import` command as you have suggested. I'm looking to import data while the emulator is running, so that I do not have to restart it.

Comment: @NateMay as I have mentioned steps following reference article https://github.com/RobinaMirbahar/Google-Cloud-Solutions/blob/main/Import%20emulator%20data%20while%20the%20emulator%20is%20running. while running you can import